# Copy Object Values

Tags: objective-c, copy

I have a method that receives an array and then stores this in the NSObject properties.

```
- (void)updatePoints:(NSArray *)pointArrayPassed
{
    pointArray = pointArrayPassed;
    pointCount= pointArray.count;
}
```

The following code works but obviously keeps the pointer of pointArrayPassed so when I can that it reflects down the call stack.  However if I use a copy of the pointArrayPassed then the app starts to leak heavily!

Is there a way in the function to pass just the values as such instead of the pointer?

Comment: How do you copy it? `pointArray = [pointArrayPassed copy]`?

Comment: Yes, sorry forgot to add that

Comment: I can't understand what you're saying.  You don't specify how your variables are declared, what their lifetime is, etc, or what you mean by "so when I can that it reflects down the call stack".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just keep sticking copies in an iVar without releasing the current object. Otherwise you've lost the pointer to which you can send the `release` message - which is why it leaks all over the place.

This is a better replacement.

```
- (void)updatePoints:(NSArray *)pointArrayPassed
{
    if (pointArray == pointArrayPassed) {
        //the new array is the same as the current one. Do nothing
        return;
    }
    [pointArray release];
    pointArray = [pointArrayPassed copy];
    pointCount = pointArray.count;

}
```

**But** it's not the most elegant way of doing it.

A better way is to declare pointArray as an property with `copy` as its memory management semantic (which is obvious as you have a mutable/immutable class cluster). And have a separate method called `-pointCount` which returns the count when required.